# How to find out which fonts are included on a page?

Tags: javascript, fonts, font-face

I need to get a list of all font names that are available for use on the page via `@font-face` declarations (whether in external stylesheets or inline `<style>` elements). This is for a script that will be included on pages I do not control.

Ideally I'd like to do this *without* re-downloading all CSS files over AJAX and then parsing them.

But I can't use the new [document.fonts](http://dev.w3.org/csswg/css-font-loading/) API because I need this to be reasonably cross-browser (even IE7 if possible).

Is there any way to do this without downloading and parsing the CSS?

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9180184/access-css-file-contents-via-javascript

Comment: Looks like you could loop over document.styleSheets and look at the cssRules attribute (or "rules" for some browsers) for each sheet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think something like this would be a start:

```
var sheets = document.styleSheets,
    sheet,
    rule,
    i, j;

for (i = 0; i < sheets.length; i++) {
  sheet = sheets[i];
  for (j = 0; j < sheet.rules.length; j++) {
    rule = sheet.rules[j];
    if (typeof(rule.cssText) !== 'undefined' && rule.cssText.indexOf("font-face") !== -1) {
       console.log(rule.cssText); // you can parse the font name from rule.cssText here
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Check below code, it might help

```
var ruleFontName = [];
$.each(document.styleSheets, function(sheetIndex, sheet) {
    $.each(sheet.cssRules || sheet.rules, function(ruleIndex, rule) {
        if (typeof(rule.cssText) !== 'undefined' && rule.cssText.indexOf("font-face") !== -1) {
        var fntSrc = (rule.cssText. match(/src: *url\(([^;]+)\);/i) || ["", ""])[1];
        var fntName = (rule.cssText.match(/font-family: *([^;]+);/i) || ["", ""])[1];
        add(ruleFontName,fntSrc,fntName )
       }
    });
});

//checking if array values are not repeated


     function add(arr, src, name) {
            var foundName = arr.some(function (el) {
              return el.fntName === name;
            });
            var foundSrc = arr.some(function (el) {
              return el.fntSrc === src;
            });
            if (!foundName && !foundSrc) {
                arr.push({ fntName: name, fntSrc: src });
                console.log(arr);
            }

        }
```

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/hiteshbhilai2010/dpfpLyq1/47/) : http://jsfiddle.net/hiteshbhilai2010/dpfpLyq1/47/